# How to simulate a button click using code?

Tags: android, onclick

How can I trigger a button click event using code in Android? I want to trigger the button click programmatically when some other event occurs.

Same Problem I am Facing

```
public void onDateSelectedButtonClick(View v){
    /*Something  Alarm Management 
    http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/Alarmdemo.htm
    copied code from this site*/
}
```

Button code:

```
<Button
    android:onClick="onDateSelectedButtonClick"
    android:text="Set notification for this date" />
```

But I want to call that function OnLoadLayout without OnClickEvent

Comment: can you please specify the problem? why do you want that? Do you want to trigger some code to be executed?

Comment: yes, i want to trigger the code to be executed for the button click.

Answer (score 482, accepted):

there is a better way.

```
View.performClick();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()

this should answer all your problems.  every View inherits this function, including Button, Spinner, etc.

Just to clarify, View does not have a static performClick() method. You must call performClick() on an instance of View.
For example, you can't just call

```
View.performClick();
```

Instead, do something like:

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.myview);
myView.performClick();
```

Comment: But what is the View for Android's back button?

Comment: how can get back button view?

Comment: there is no "View" for the back button on your phone.  you need to use key listeners to get those button presses.  that's a different issue altogether.

Comment: @moon - If you want to have people notified of your comments, start them with "@" and the first few letters of the user who you want notified.... (authors of the commented on post automatically get notified, but commenters do not)

Comment: To simulate _BACK_ button press you can just call `onBackPressed()` from your activity code (added in API8)

Comment: The code shown in this answer is a little confusing. Just to clarify, View does not have a static performClick() method. You must call performClick() on an instance of View.

Comment: is correct, because button not is a button, works, because button is a view, all layers (textview/scroll/button... ) extends view, view.performClick(), only invoke click into view,

Comment: Is there any way for performing click on Google Maps Marker ?

Comment: this is not working in case of dialog list and menu item.

Answer (score 55):

Just to clarify what moonlightcheese stated:
To trigger a button click event through code in Android
provide the following:

```
buttonName.performClick();
```

Answer (score 14):

you can do it this way

```
private Button btn;
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn.performClick();
```

Answer (score 9):

Just write this simple line of code :-

```
button.performClick();
```

where button is the reference variable of Button class and defined as follows:-

```
private Button buttonToday ;
buttonToday = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToday);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 7):

Android's `callOnClick()` ([added in API 15](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#callOnClick%28%29)) can sometimes be a better choice in my experience than `performClick()`. If a user has selection sounds enabled, then `performClick()` could cause the user to hear two continuous selection sounds that are somewhat layered on top of each other which can be jarring. (One selection sound for the user's first button click, and then another for the other button's `OnClickListener` that you're calling via code.)

Answer (score 7):

Starting with API15, you can use also `callOnClick()` that directly call attached view OnClickListener. Unlike performClick(), this only calls the listener, and does not do any associated clicking actions like reporting an accessibility event.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not use the `sender` argument, why not refactor the button handler implementation to separate function, and call it from wherever you want (from the button handler and from the other place).

Anyway, it is a better and cleaner design - a code that needs to be called on button handler AND from some other places deserves to be refactored to own function. Plus it will help you separate UI handling from application logic code. You will also have a nice name to the function,  not just onDateSelectedButtonClick().