# Execute Button in seconds Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way for a button to be executed in seconds without touching it.
The following code execute the button in one second but after i touch the button. My question is can this be achieved without touching the button?

```
View.OnClickListener mButtonStartListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(hMyTimeTask);
            //        Parameters
            //        r  The Runnable that will be executed.
            //        delayMillis  The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.
            mHandler.postDelayed(hMyTimeTask, 1000); // delay 1 second
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};


private Runnable hMyTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        nCounter++;
        hTextView.setText("Hallo from thread counter: " + nCounter);
    }
};
/**
 *
 */
View.OnClickListener mButtonStopListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(hMyTimeTask);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simulate click event by following code

`View.performClick();`

originally posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877526/5329101.

Comment: Thanks Dmitey Bulashevich's

Answer (score 0):

Try .onLoadCompleteListener instead of .onClickListener