# Android studio click on coords x y

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, button, motionevent

Hi i want when i clicked on button automatically button2 is click with MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        500,
                        935,
                        0);

```
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.boutton);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    500,
                    935,
                    0);
            view.dispatchTouchEvent(me);

        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: Please check the following answer. [How to simulate a button click using code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553374/how-to-simulate-a-button-click-using-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `performClick()` method to achieve this by using it inside the onClickListener of `button`

```java
View.performClick();
```

Please check the following answers for more understanding:

[How to simulate a button click using code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553374/how-to-simulate-a-button-click-using-code)

[Simulate Android button click programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579976/simulate-android-button-click-programmatically)

Also check the following documentation:
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick())

Comment: Glad I could help.